# Get JSON values and convert them into Java variables

Tags: java, json

I get the following JSON from a server and I would like to save all the values in different variables. Now everything is saved as one string variable.

```
{"firstName":"Jim","lastName":"Smith"}
```

What I would like to is to separate them and put them into two variables like in the example below. The `firstName` and `lastName` will be various, depending on what the server is sending to me.

```
String personFirstName= "Jim";

String personLastName = "Smith";
```

Comment: Did you already search for existing libraries for handling JSON data in Java...? Or did you try anything else so far?

Comment: I have been searching for a while now without finding any solution that I could implement. I have also tried out several solutions that I have found on the internet, but non of them helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use one of many  JSON processing libraries available.

Examples are [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Both of them allow to convert: json string <--> object

You should start with defining domain model:

```
public class Person {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   // getters/setters
}
```

Then you should do like this (for example, for GSON):

```
String json = "{\"firstName\":\"Jim\",\"lastName":\"Smith\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person person = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

An example for you:

Read Json into **str** (a string value), then:

```
JSONObject obj= new JSONObject(str);
String personFirstName = obj.getString("firstName");
String personLastName = obj.getString("lastName");
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `String` in `JSONObject`:

```java
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

And after get the fields:

```
object.getString("firstName");
```